# Jquery toggles on the same click event

Tags: jquery

Is there a much better way to toggle click right after window load? the code is working though, it's just I'm not sure this is the right way.

The code below should trigger the click event(element) and after a few seconds it will click back the same element.

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#burger-icon').click();
    }, 1500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#burger-icon').click();
    }, 4000);
});
```